# What does this notation mean? Simulation exercise

Tags: simulation

Let $F(\textbf{x})$ be the multivariate normal distribution function. A exercise question requires us to simulate from $$dF_\varepsilon(\textbf{x}) = Ce^{\langle\varepsilon, \textbf{x}\rangle} \, dF(\textbf{x})$$

for some normalizing constant $C$ and some $\varepsilon$.

I've never seen this notation before. What does it mean? In particular, the $dF$ notation and the $\langle \varepsilon, \textbf{x}\rangle$ notation confuses me. Is $\varepsilon$ a constant or a vector of constants?

The purpose of the exercise is some sort of important sampling. How does that fit into here? In importance sampling, we simulate from density $g$, and scale the results by $f/g$ where $f$ is the original density. I don't see how that fits in here?

How would you simulate from this?

Comment: One would *guess,* having no more information, that $\epsilon$ is a vector of constants and $\langle \epsilon, \mathbf{X}\rangle = \epsilon_1 x_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_n x_n$ is the dot product of $\epsilon$ and $\mathbf x.$  I, personally, would not use importance sampling for this, because $F_\epsilon$ is just another multivariate Normal distribution, which raises some doubts about my guess; but possibly the whole point is that you could use this observation to check the validity of your simulation based on importance sampling.

Comment: Adding to the comment from @whuber  dF is the multivariate standard normal density, so $dF(0) = \phi(0) = 1/\sqrt{2 \pi}$.

Comment: @AdamO That's the case only for the *univariate* density.

Comment: @whuber It was an illustrative example. More detail: $dF([0, 0, \ldots, 0]) = \phi(0)^n $.

Comment: I will add that to familiarize yourself with some measure theoretic notation (like $dF(x)$) a decent reference may be Real Analysis by McDonald and Weiss.

Comment: The density, except when the variance matrix $V\in\mathbf R^{n\times n}$ is singular, is
$$
\text{constant} \times \exp\left(\frac{-1}2 (\mathbf x - \mu)' V^{-1} (\mathbf x - \mu) \right).
$$
Probably the notation $\langle\varepsilon,\mathbf x\rangle$ means $\varepsilon_1 x_1 + \cdots + \varepsilon_n x_n = \varepsilon' \mathbf x.$ So inside the exponential function we have
$$
\varepsilon' \mathbf x -\frac 1 2 (\mathbf x -\mu)'V^{-1} (\mathbf x - \mu)$$ This seems to ask for a sort of completion of the square to find the new point to replace $\mu. \qquad$